# unable to see left image from bumblebee2

Tags: ros, bumblebee2, image, bumblebee

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all

I am trying to work with a bumblebee camera to use it for VSLAM, but when I launch the bumblebee node, I'm only able to see the image of the right camera properly. The image from the left camera is very distorted.

I initially thought that my camera was faulty, but even after I replaced the bumblebee with a new piece I still have the same issue!

does anyone know how to fix this problem?

cheers,
divya

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11958/unable-to-see-left-image-from-bumblebee2/) by [Divya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1220/divya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already solved it!

okay for those who have the same issue - refer to point 5 in this link

http://answers.ros.org/question/1118/bumblebee2-640x480-under-diamondback

---

Originally posted by [Divya](https://answers.ros.org/users/1220/divya/) with karma: 46 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0